# The type name 'Now' does not exist in the type 'DateTime'

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

I am making a quiz app cross-platform using Xamarin and C# in Visual Studio 2017. The problem occurs with this line of code:

```
DateTime today = new DateTime.Now;
```

Visual Studio underlines the `.Now` and claims that "The type name 'Now' does not exist in the type 'DateTime'."

The code's goal is to get the system time and display it in a textbox (as well as to create a date for the notecard constructor). 
Because of `.Now`, Visual Studio declares "The type name 'Now' does not exist in the type 'DateTime'.

I also tried using `System.DateTime.Now`, but that didn't yield any better result, as the header already includes `System`. Below is the template, which is the standard C# for an XAML page:

```
namespace DenisQuiz.UWP
{
   // This page allows the user to create a new study set.
   public sealed partial class CreateNewStudySet : Page
   {
      DateTime today = new DateTime.Now;

      public CreateNewStudySet()
      {
         this.InitializeComponent();

         automaticTodaysDate.Text = today.ToString();
      }
   }
}
```

This is doubtless a simple solution, but I've looked through the documentation, and no one seems to have this problem, and documentation suggests this exact usage:

```
DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Is there a way to correct the problem as set up currently, or must I use another method to get the time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are doing wrong here

```
              DateTime today = new DateTime.Now;
```

You have to new the DateTime Object. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx. In the below example I am passing year , month and day.

```
            DateTime today = new DateTime(2017,12,1); // or other constructor
```

or simply use which return DateTime instance with current year , current month and current day based on your system/server datetime.

```
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: So instead of creating a ``new`` object, I just get it.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` will give you the instance so there is no need to use `new`